# Cython error while installing pandas from setup.py

Tags: python, pandas, cython, setup.py, cythonize

Facing some errors related to cython while installing pandas from setup.py. Unable to fix that error. I'm trying to install the library offline with setup.py

```
[16/40] Cythonizing pandas\_libs/reduction.pyx
    
    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
    
            self.orig_data = self.buf.data
            self.orig_len = self.buf.shape[0]
            self.orig_stride = self.buf.strides[0]
    
            self.buf.data = self.values.data    
    
    pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx:472:15: Assignment to a read-only property
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "setup.py", line 791, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "setup.py", line 761, in setup_package
            ext_modules=maybe_cythonize(extensions, compiler_directives=directives),
          File "setup.py", line 540, in maybe_cythonize
            return cythonize(extensions, *args, **kwargs)
          File "D:\Pickle Examples\examples_aix\example_aix\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1110, in cythonize
            cythonize_one(*args)
          File "D:\Pickle Examples\examples_aix\example_aix\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1277, in cythonize_one
            raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
        Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: pandas\_libs/reduction.pyx
```

Comment: Which Cython version do you use? This is the problematic change: https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/22a49f403b6f00f1674664e01ee0f8212c06ef13#diff-24bcfc3298e43281fed97318a554550dL247

Comment: Latest version 3.0a6 (Pre-release)

Comment: Ok, it is not yet realeased: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0.29.x/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L248. Use Cython 0.29.xx

Comment: Ya, it's working fine now thanks.